# Is it possible to force a set of ColdFusion remote access calls through a filter?

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Is it possible to send the results of a CFC's remote access functions through a filter?

Something with a component like this:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="foo" access="remote" returnformat="json" securejson="false">
        <cfscript>
            return {
                "a": "<script>alert('l33t');</script>"
            };
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>   
</cfcomponent>
```

The desired result being returned to the client with values filtered/mapped/reduced/whatever, for example just running values through `encodeForHtml`:

```
{
    "a": "&lt;script&gt;alert&#x28;&#x27;l33t&#x27;&#x29;&#x3b;&lt;&#x2f;script&gt;"
}
```

(that escaped sequence might not be exacting, but the gist is there)

The goal being to build some filter implemented somewhere on the server that targets a set of administrator specified components, and without *explicit additional code* in those components, filters all http responses originating from them.

Preferably entirely from CF, but maybe we can sell the bossman on involving Tomcat / IIS?

Comment: You can probably do it from the application.cfc onCFCRequest() method.